# Square of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Find a polynomial with more than one nonzero term such that its square has exactly same number of terms as the original polynomial.

Attempts-I tried to use variables for the polynomial and equate some to $0$. I also found that it is not possible for degree $1,2,3$. But I could not find a way how to find such a polynomial.
Source - EJ Barbeau Polynomial.

[image]

Comment: Edit the title square not sqare?

Comment: consider $y=x$, $y^2 = x^2$ still the same number of terms or is this not what you meant?

Comment: When the polynomial is squared and the number of non zero terms is same as the original polynomial

Comment: Is 0 an answer to the question?

Comment: @dan_fulea: Any constant polynomial will be an answer.

Comment: Infinite polynomial is also an answer

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary: That is a power series, not a polynomial.

Comment: @clayton But still $\infty^2=\infty$

Comment: @abhishek that's not a polynomial (I hear an echo)

Comment: There have been a little bit of change in the problem as the statement says it has more than one non zero terms

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary: I agree (mostly), but the problem is that you aren't starting with a polynomial. A power series squared is still a power series.

Comment: @clayton i just wanted to have a definition of the number of terms... The question uses some variables and wanted to equate some to 0, so the question came with the radical try to equate them all to 0..

Comment: Brill where did you get the problem ????????????????????

Comment: Please clarify your question, Brilli, as an *edit to your actual question post*, and please, answer @WillJagy's answer, too?

Comment: Example- number of terms in x^2+x^3 is 2 but in x^2+x^3+1 is 3.

Comment: The problem is from Ej Barbeaus polynomial book

Comment: Please clarify your question, Brilli, as ***an edit to your actual question post (above), instead of offering a moving target of questions in the comments. And also share there where you encountered the problem.***  Most readers who might want to answer your question are not going to look for clarification in the comments.  Hence, it is your job to adjust the actual question post to match what you are telling us in the comments.

Comment: http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~zarkom/Polynomials_EJBarbeau.pdf

Comment: this is Exploration E.1. on book page 6.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left( {x}^{4}+\sqrt{2}\; {x}^{3}-{x}^{2}+\sqrt {2}\;x+1 \right) ^{2}={x}
^{8}+2\,\sqrt {2}\;{x}^{7}+7\,{x}^{4}+2\,\sqrt {2}\;x+1
$$

Comment: Robert Israel  could you tell how you got to the answer??

Comment: Set the $x^2, x^3, x^5, x^6$ coefficients to $0$ in $(x^4 +c_3 x^3 + c_2 x^2 + c_1 x+1)^2$, and solve.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying too that way. I thought there would be an alternative.

Comment: Did you solve this with a computer or is there a natural reason to think that one should start with a $4$th degree polynomial? (I don't have any intuition that says $4$th degree should work, other than just cranking out the formulas).

Comment: I believed Brilli's statement that degrees $1,2,3$ don't work.  $4$ is the next one to try.

Comment: If one prefers to get rid of the $\sqrt 2$'s, $(4x^4+4x^3-2x^2+2x+1)^2=16x^8+32x^7+28x^4+4x+1)$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I see, haha. I thought you may have had some incredible intuition. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is there a particular reason you chose to set those particular coefficients to $0$, as opposed to a different selection?

Comment: Sometimes symmetry is your friend.

Comment: But that means for any degree there is only one such polynomial.

Comment: What means that, and why?